# What is recommended file suffix for Thymeleaf templates?

Tags: thymeleaf

I see that JSP pages have `.jsp`/`.jspf`/`.jspx` suffixes (from *JavaServer Pages™ Specification Version2.2*), Velocity templates uses `.vm` suffix, FreeMarker uses `.ftl` suffix.

What is recommended file suffix for Thymeleaf templates **according to official body/docs/IDE expectation**?

`.html` suffix can mislead with pure HTML 5 files. For that reason I think about putting all Thymleaf templates into `thy/` hierarchy and pure HTML files keep inside `html/` directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thymeleaf uses *natural templates*. A HTML5 Thymeleaf template can (and should) be a valid HTML document. Therefore these templates do not need its own extension, opposite to for example Velocity and Freemarker.

To distinguish Thymeleaf templates from other HTML files you could put them in a directory called `templates`, this is what the official Spring integration tutorial uses.